# Log GPU usage per process

Tags: logging, gpu, monitoring

Which program would help me log GPU usage, **per process**. Output should be a file, or anything that can be inspected afterwards.

My PC always uses the GPU quite a lot when I am *afk*, and stops when I touch the mouse and the screen wakes back up again. I want to make sure my PC is really (kind of) idle, when I leave it idle.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I have discovered that you can monitor GPU usage with [process explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx). You can hover over the graph and see what the usage was for the last 10 minutes or so.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? I want to find out which process caused the increase.